# Howto use psexec via powershell invoke-command on a remote computer? (invalid handle)

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, psexec

I have written a powershell script which creates a powershell script or a batch script depending on the remote host on which this script should be started remotely (either via powershell invoke-command or psexec).

The script creates either a powershell or a batch script, because not all hosts on which these created scripts should be run support WinRM (Windows Remote Management).

The created scripts include some psexec lines which executes a command on another remote host. The created batch script works as expected, but from the created powershell script i get the following errors from the psexec calls.

```
NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : <HOSTNAME REPLACED>

PsExec v2.1 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
The handle is invalid.
Access is denied.
Connecting to 10.XXX.XXX.127...Couldn't access 10.XXX.XXX.127:
Starting PSEXESVC service on 10.XXX.XXX.127...Could not start PSEXESVC service on 10.XXX.XXX.127:
Connecting to 10.XXX.XXX.127...Starting PSEXESVC service on 10.XXX.XXX.127...
```

Here is a small overview of what is done:

1. Powershell script on deployment host creates the rollout script (ps1 or batch) depending on the destination host
2. Powershell script on deployment host starts the created rollout script on the destination host

   - Powershell will be started via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <destination host> -FilePath <path to created script> -Authentication default`
   - Batch will be started via `& psexec.exe \\<destination host> -n 60 -accepteula -c -f <path to created script>`
3. Created rollout script on the destination host executes a psexec command to start a service on a third host (this fails only if the rollout script is powershell)

This is the psexec command which fails if executed via a remotely started powershell script.

`& psexec.exe \\<destination host> -n 60 -accepteula -u <user> -p <password> net stop <servicename>`

The same command `psexec.exe \\<destination host> -n 60 -accepteula -u <user> -p <password> net stop <servicename>` executed via a remotely started batch script works without problems.

**Update #1**

Also if i connect to the destination host with rdp and start a powershell shell and paste the command it works without issues. The problem only occurs if started remotely.

I already tried the following variants of starting psexec, all without luck!

1. `& psexec.exe \\<destination host> -n 60 -accepteula -s -u <user> -p <password> net stop <servicename>`
2. `Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential "<domain>\<user>" -WorkingDirectory $env:systemdrive -ArgumentList "/C psexec.exe \\<destination host> -n 60 -accepteula -u <user> -p <password> net stop <servicename>"`
3. `Start-Process powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory $env:systemdrive -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "cmd.exe /C psexec.exe \\<destination host> -n 60 -accepteula -u <user> -p <password> net stop <servicename>"`

Answer (score 0):

can you try to replace your psexec command, and use cmd.exe like thisn also add -s to psexec so it will run as system user. My testing command :

```
icm -cn computer1  -ScriptBlock{ cmd.exe "/c psexec -s -u <login> -p <password> /accepteula /n 10 \\computer2 net start audiosrv"}
```

Comment: This psexec part is not the only code in the rollout script, but i know what you mean. I will update the original question with all variants i already tried.

Comment: icm is an alias of invoke-command, i dont see it in your tested commands. please try as i did, it worked fine in my env.

Comment: i could not use icm for the psexec part, because the destination hosts are w2k3 systems without WinRM. I think you missed the information which architecture i use. Powershell script on host A starts a powershell script on host B which then starts psexec like shown above.

Comment: if you run that command from hostA , and replace computer1 with your hostB it will fullfill your requirements no ?

Comment: the problem is, that the psexec command has to be run after several other commands on host B so i'm not sure if it is possible in any way to solve this, but i will give  it a try.

Comment: In our test environment the idea to execute the psexec command from host A to host C works without problems, but in the production environment host A could not reach the host C's. Sadly this is no final solution as it wouldn't work in our production.

Comment: i have no idea what your developement or production looks like. You will have to narrow your question to a minimal, reproductible case and provide more details

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the Second Hop problem:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx

The answer is to enable the appropriate relationship between the two computers involved (see previous link or just search google for 'powershell' and 'second hop') and to add to Invoke-Command:
  -Authentication Credssp -Credential

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:
Start-Process -FilePath .\PsExec.exe -ArgumentList "/acceptEula /s \$Computer program.exe /arg"